# Odoo10 not updating model

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-10

Odoo10 / Windows

I installed a module "my_app" in Odoo10, and want to change the model : app_model.py following this steps :

- add field to app_model.py and save it
- restart the odoo server form windows "services"
- Activate developper mode
- Update the application list
- Upgrade the application

The problem is that when i open my app model in the configuration menu=>Database structure=>models , the added field doesn't appear

I tried to uninstall the app (to install it later with the new model), but Odoo didn't remove the app_model from the list of models (after app list update, restart service and even retart the server).

did i miss something ?

Comment: added field presented in xml?

Comment: at this stage, i just want to see my model updated in database structure.

Comment: inherit that model and define field

Comment: What happens if you delete your model file, restart Odoo (that will find an error), and then put it back and restart Odoo again?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem, it was due to an Indentation error.

When i added the field, i used linebreak in the editor, so it was at the same level of the other fields. But the editor used automatically tab when the other fields were indented with spaces.

It was that simple, but gave me a headache.